# sameas condition for equality test in jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Is `sameas()` in jinaj2 strictly to check booleans (true, false?)

It doesn't work the same as the equal test and I am wondering what is the use case of it beside checking booleans.

"Check if an object points to the same memory address..."

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#sameas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's for instance checking, versus using `==` which in python is subject to calling the object's `__equals__` method, which may be overridden and thus do something unexpected

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: |
     {%- set a = {"something": True} -%}
     {%- set b = {"something": True} -%}
     equals = {{ a == b }}
     sameas = {{ a is sameas b }}
```

yields

```
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: |-
    equals = True
    sameas = False
```

I'm sure there is some good use case for it, but in all my years of ansible-ing I've never once had to use it, so take that as one data point